# How to asynchronously set initial value for React context API in NextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my NextJS e-commerce app, I'm trying to use the React context API to keep track of a user's shopping cart. I want to fetch the cart contents from MongoDB to initialise the cart context, but I'm unsure of how to do this, given that the context provider is in a file marked "use client".

What I'd like to do is something similar to this:

```js
'use client';
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const BasketContext = createContext<any>([]);

export async function BasketContextProvider({ children }: {children:React.ReactNode}) {
  const value = await fetchCartContentsFromMongoDB();

  return <BasketContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</BasketContext.Provider>;
}
```

but client components cannot be marked async. How can I use a provider to expose a value whose initial value is set asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getInitialProps`.
For example,

```
BasketContextProvider.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const value = await fetchCartContentsFromMongoDB();
  return { value }
}

const BasketContext = createContext<any>([]);

export async function BasketContextProvider({ children, value }: {children:React.ReactNode; value: any}) {
  return <BasketContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</BasketContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: Next.js documentation is showing `getInitialProps()` as "a legacy API". Is there a supported alternative?

Comment: I think that `getStaticProps` is doing same thing.